# Debugging error when editing code

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Occasionally I get this strange error when debugging code. It occurs when I change something in code while debugging.

This isn't really linked to the framework, as this was happening in different versions so far.

*Translated from german:*

```
Error 1 The sourcefile "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\8\.NETFramework,
Version=v4.5.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs" 
could not be opened("Unknown Error").   folderOfProjectFile
```

The whole directory "8" isn't existant in `appdata\local`
there is only "4"

Additional Info:

- Visual Studio Premium 2013, though I bellieve it happened in 2010 too.
- Terminalserver running 2008 RC2 DataCenter x64

There isn't much Google offers when searching for this errormessage. Mostly because my translation probably isn't exactly the correct one.

Here is the original exception

```
Fehler  3   Die Quelldatei "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\5\.NETFramework,
Version=v4.5.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs" 
konnte nicht geöffnet werden ("Unbekannter Fehler ").     folderOfProjectfile
```

Does anyone know what could cause this problem?

Comment: What specifically are you doing when this happens?

Comment: something simple like changing the order of a string-concatination.
from a = b + c to a = b + "\\" + c;

Comment: Have you configured to download the .NET source files from the MS Symbol Servers?

Comment: Well it was configured to Download all Symbols, but no symbolserver was chosen

Comment: Is the string you are changing a file path?

Comment: yes. But to a temporary file.

Comment: Is this error very sporadic or only when code is changed while debugging? Could you also dump, the actual error text (without the translation)

Comment: Having trouble to reproduce it atm.

Comment: So yes, it is very sporadic. Happens only when code is changed while debugging

Comment: Looks like fumbling around with the Symbolsettings did the trick. Thank you

Comment: Well its occuring again. Added the "original" exception

Comment: My answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57952281/5480409)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have run into this issue sporadically. It has occurred for me in 2 ways:

- The file existed in a different folder.
- The settings in the file did not match what visual studio expected.

I resolved both situations the same way:

1. Close the project, and preferably VS
2. Delete the solution's *.SUO file
3. Additionally, I also remove any `C:\Users\*\AppData\local\Temp\*\.NETFramework,*.AssemblyAttributes.cs` file from my profile's local temp folder(s).

Comment: Worked like a charm! The thing that was confusing me is the file is actually called ".NETFramework,*.AssemblyAttributes.cs"

Answer (score 1):

Go to the folder:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp
```

and make sure the following file is not hidden:

```
".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
```